# HTML Escape in T-SQL SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a column in a SQL Server database that stores a text block in the following fashion:

```html
<HTML><HEAD><style type="text/css">BODY,TD,TH,BUTTON,INPUT,SELECT,TEXTAREA{FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR: black; FONT-FAMILY: Arial,Helvetica;}BODY{MARGIN: 5px;}P,DIV,UL,OL,BLOCKQUOTE{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px;}</style></HEAD><BODY> <p style="MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px">Patient is a&nbsp;84 year old female.&nbsp; Patient's histpry includes the following:</p> <p style="MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px">&nbsp;</p></BODY></HTML>​
```

All I want to bring back from this particular example above would be:

```
Patient is an 84 year old female. Patient's histpry includes the following:
```

I honestly do not even know where to start, is there any HTML escape type functions in SQL Server 2014? I do not have access to CLI and I will need to run the code inside of a stored procedure that I have been tasked with creating.

Comment: This is best handled in the client code. You won't find good SQL tools for this, and even if you do, the database server isn't the better place for that logic.

Comment: Attention: The very last character of your sample is an invisible character, which might lead to troubles...

Comment: It in fact does, I might be able to unicode replace it away, but your solution was rather elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If open to a Table-Valued Function, consider the following.

Tired of extracting strings (left, right, charindex, patindex, reverse, etc), I modified a split/parse function to accept two non-like delimiters.  In this case `>` and `</`

Also, being a TVF, it is easy to incorporate into a CROSS APPLY if you data is in a table.

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max)='<HTML><HEAD><style type="text/css">BODY,TD,TH,BUTTON,INPUT,SELECT,TEXTAREA{FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR: black; FONT-FAMILY: Arial,Helvetica;}BODY{MARGIN: 5px;}P,DIV,UL,OL,BLOCKQUOTE{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px;}</style></HEAD><BODY> <p style="MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px">Patient is a&nbsp;84 year old female.&nbsp; Patient''s histpry includes the following:</p> <p style="MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px">&nbsp;</p></BODY></HTML>​'

Select *
 From  [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](replace(@S,'&nbsp;',' '),'>','</')
 Where RetVal<>' '
   and RetVal not like 'BODY,%'
```

**Returns**

```
RetSeq  RetPos  RetVal
2       284     Patient is a 84 year old female.  Patient's histpry includes the following:
```

**Note:** The WHERE is optional and may have to be tweaked to suite you actual needs.  Just for fun, try it without the WHERE.  Also, in this example, we trapped the `&nbsp;`, but as you know, there may be many others i.e. `&mdash;`.

**The Function if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter1 varchar(100),@Delimiter2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
       cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A ),
       cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
       cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
      ,RetPos = N
      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1) 
 From  (
        Select *,RetVal = Substring(@String, N, L) 
         From  cte4
       ) A
 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1

)
/*
Max Length of String 1MM characters

Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```

Comment: I think you just entered "god mode" lol. But seriously thank you I will try this and see if I can tweak it as needed. Hopefully my counterpart can find a more appropriate method to get this done in Crystal.

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator "god mode"?... Hardly...  We're all standing on the shoulders of giants.   Thanks for the grin.

Comment: I used this as the solution because the column data cannot always be parsed to XML, really appreciate the help

Answer (score 2):

With HTML you never can be sure, that the cast to XML will be successful. But, after replacing `&nbsp;` with simple blanks, you might go like this:

```
Declare @S varchar(max)='<HTML><HEAD><style type="text/css">BODY,TD,TH,BUTTON,INPUT,SELECT,TEXTAREA{FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR: black; FONT-FAMILY: Arial,Helvetica;}BODY{MARGIN: 5px;}P,DIV,UL,OL,BLOCKQUOTE{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px;}</style></HEAD><BODY> <p style="MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px">Patient is a&nbsp;84 year old female.&nbsp; Patient''s histpry includes the following:</p> <p style="MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px">&nbsp;</p></BODY></HTML>​'

SELECT CAST(REPLACE(@S,'&nbsp;',' ') AS XML).value('(//p/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)');
```

The result

```
Patient is a 84 year old female.  Patient's histpry includes the following:
```

Comment: My first thought as well, but NOW I understand why it did not parse as XML.   +1

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I just found out, that it would also work to define your own entities. It works to place `'<!DOCTYPE html [<!ENTITY nbsp " ">]>'` in front of the HTML-string and use `CONVERT()` with format-option 2. But this is limited... Anyway, reading html as xml is very often the wrong choice and can break at any time...

Comment: Three quick items.   1) "I just found out" coming from YOU is encouraging for folks like me.  2) Now have to explore your tip.  3) Parsing HTML is actually the reason why I created the function.  I have a client where we parse 40,000 pages from 7 sites daily.   Your friendly stalker... John

Comment: @JohnCappelletti 